# Python date time formatting - String to a specified format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am looking to convert raw string to a specified data time format.

Here's the sample data:

```
0              47 mins
1       1 hour 25 mins
2       1 hour 27 mins
3               6 mins
```

Is the above one of the supported date time formats in python that can be transformed using some function - to_datetime or strftime? or would this need to handled/parsed out differently.

Expected format:

```
00:47
01:25
01:27
00:06
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 potential formats, so you can try them each:

```
s = pd.Series(['47 mins', '1 hour 25 mins', '1 hour 27 mins', '6 mins'])

dt1 = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%H hour %M mins', errors='coerce')
dt2 = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%M mins', errors='coerce')

res = dt1.fillna(dt2).dt.strftime('%H:%M')

print(res)

0    00:47
1    01:25
2    01:27
3    00:06
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert some keywords to appropriate things to be passed to `pandas.Timedelta`

```
d = {'mins': 'minutes', 'secs': 'seconds', 'hour': 'hours'}
td = [
    pd.Timedelta(**dict(zip(s[1::2], map(float, s[::2]))))
    for s in [s.split() for s in s.replace(d, regex=True)]
]

pd.Series(td, s.index)

0   00:47:00
1   01:25:00
2   01:27:00
3   00:06:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Solution looks elegant. If you don't mind, can you add a few comments around the td block.

Comment: This solution does look neat :). I have sneaky feeling that repeated built-in `str.replace` without regex will be more efficient than `pd.Series.replace(regex=True)`.